# Automapper - Bestpractice of mapping a many-to-many association into a flat object

Tags: c#, many-to-many, associations, automapper, object-object-mapping

I have two entities: `Employee` and `Team`.

[image]

What I want is an `EmployeeForm` that has the `Name` of the `Team`.

[image]

How can I achieve this using **AutoMapper**?

My current "solution" is the following:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeForm>()
                           .ForMember(dest => dest.TeamName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.GetTeams().FirstOrDefault() != null ? string.Join(", ", x.GetTeams().Select(y=>y.Name)) : "n/a"));
```

In my opinion this is bad readable.

What I would like to have is a generic method where I can pass an entity, choosing the collection and saying if collection is null return a default value or otherwise choose the property of the collection via lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rethinked my whole design starting to change the **domain model**:

[image]

I changed the `many-to-many association` into two `one-to-many associations` using a relation table.

With this more easier **domain model**, I can easily map this into a **flat DTO** using **AutoMapper**.

```
public class TeamEmployeeMapperProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<TeamEmployee, TeamEmployeeForm>();
    }
}
```

Yes that's all :)

Here is the flat view model object.

[image]

Comment: If this works for you, that is good.  However, I'm not sure I'd be comfortable changing my domain model *only* to allow easier integration with some other utility/library.

Comment: yes that seems so, but it isn't. It is a problem in general in my opinion. Many-to-many associations are too difficult to handle. I made this experience with NHibernate and now with AutoMapper. But as I said, this is not a problem of the tools it is the association itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a read-only string property on Employee called "TeamNames".  Put the list-building logic in there.  That way, you've got a property that is testable (vs. the lambda expression) and it will make your mapping easier.

Comment: your idea sounds not bad, I will try this later =)

Comment: @Patrick, your solution does not help. You would have duplicate entries. So an employee with two teams would be displayed twice. You could distinct the list, but when paging comes into play you get problems. The total count wouldn't be correct and the row numbers, too. I tried to answer my question, please feel free to review.

Comment: Not sure how you see duplicate entries being generated (unless you allow an employee to be added to the same team multiple times).  I'm simply advocating a string property called Employee.TeamNames (which uses your existing lambda expression to build) and change EmployeeForm.Team to EmployeeForm.TeamNames so automapper will join them without any custom mapping required.

Comment: Yes I allow to have an employee that is in more than one team

Comment: Yes I did understand your suggestion. But as I said, it is possible that an employee is a member of more than one team. This leads to duplications. You could fix this with .Distinct(), but if you want to page this you get trouble, because of wrong row numbers.

Comment: Perhaps we're straying past your original question of trying to clean up the mapping you originally posted.  My solution (when combined with a basic Mapper.CreateMap<Employee,EmployeeForm>()) will not create more than one EmployeeForm for each Employee.  I don't think continuing this conversation in comments will clarify anything since I think we're talking about different things.