# View with Many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I came across the following situation:

I have 2 tables:

Eventos and Convidados

I had to create a third table to associate multiple

id_evento and id_convidado

I've created a controller called EventoConvidado and need to display on the screen all Convidados.

How I do to pass the model to the View?

Comment: Sorry but your question isn't very clear. What data access technology are you using? What is your exact difficulty?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694632/automapper-bestpractice-of-mapping-a-many-to-many-association-into-a-flat-obje/3704643#3704643

Answer (score 0):

I found only one question in your description - how to pass a model to a view.
You create a view model called EventosConvidadosViewModel like this:

```
public class EventosConvidadosViewModel
{
  public Eventos Eventos { get; set; }
  public Convidados Convidados { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller you do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var viewModel = new EventosCandidatosViewModel();
  // should you need to fill in the parameters for the view model you do it here
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

In the view your first line should be

```
@model EventosCandidatosViewModel;
```

You use this model inside the view in the following manner: `@Model`. You access its properties like this: `@Model.Eventos` or `@Model.Convidados`.

Hope this helps you.